# Google Play Licensing (Subscription Based)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-lvl

I'm about to complete my android application.. 
I have a query regarding the application licensing and I want to charge the users on yearly basis (Subscription pattern) for the application.

Is it a possibility that can be done using subscription and In app billing.

Please point me out a working example of the same.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Subs but most likely, if you're only integrating it now, it'll be very easy to crack. -- Regarding the terminology, _LVL_ has nothing much to do with _IAB_.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look, gives you complete details [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)

Comment: Yes i have gone through this. Wanted a working example if available anywhere.
Still Thanks